# How to get AWS Cognito user data inside a lambda function protected by a cognito authorizer on API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm using serverless. I have created my user pools and protected my lambda function with a Cognito User Pool authorizer on the AWS APi gateway.

Now, inside my lambda function, I want to get my user id and other data to use as key on dynamodb storage, something like this:

```
module.exports.helloprotected = (event, context, callback) => {

      // event.request.userAttributes; -> does not work

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get it with:

```
event.requestContext
```

Other answers I found that might work on other setups/occasions:

```
event.request.userAttributes
context.authorizer
```

**Note:** In order to be able to fetch user details you should enable **Use Lambda Proxy integration** inside your API gateway (in your Integration Request) or when creating your Method.